# "2 театра есть. Я им написал... Обоим." - так можно сказать?

Tags: лексика

На `youtube` случайно наткнулся на ролик, где человек произносит фразу: "2 театра есть. Я им написал... Обоим.".  В комментарии с 49 "пальцами вверх" написано, что так нельзя говорить.

Аргументы:

- У первого человека - нужно говорить: "в оба театра".
- У второго человека - нельзя так говорить, потому, что тетр - неодушевленный.

Эти аргументы вызывают у меня некоторые сомнения, поэтому пишу этот пост.

Видео (если нужно): https://www.youtube.com/shorts/GDILT5JR3lo

Comment: Оба человека, в целом, говорят об одинаково, один говорит как нужно писать, а второй - почему так неверно. Нужно писать "в оба театра" с предлогом, потому что театры неодушевлённые. Написал обоим - говорят про людей.

Comment: @Буратино спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Это тема собирательных числительных ***двое и оба***.

**Примечание.** По поводу слов ***оба, обе*** в науке нет единого мнения. Одни лингвисты считают их указательными местоимениями в значении «и тот и другой», другие относят их к собирательным числительным на том основании, что они по значению близки числительному ***двое.***

2. Собирательное числительные **(двое, трое** и т.д.) сочетаются не со всеми существительными. **Избирательная** сочетаемость собирательных числительных определяется их **двумя** основными значениями:

(1) значением **совокупности** для некоторых **одушевленных** существительных (двое мужчин, детей, двое отдыхающих).

(2) выражением **количества** для предметов, которые употребляются только во мн. числе. (pluralia tantum): ножницы, сутки, брюки и т.д.: двое суток, трое ножниц).

3. ***Театр*** – **неодушевленное** существительное, и значение совокупности в этом случае выражает числительное ***оба (= и тот и другой)***.  Поэтому верная запись: ***в оба театра.*** Можно записать: ***в два театра***, если нужно указать только количество.
4. Числительного **обои** (И.п.) нет в русском языке. (Есть существительное "обои".)   Формы  **"в обои" (В.п.)** тоже нет.

**Склонение  *ОБА* и *ОБЕ***

```
  Именительный падеж (кто?, что?): оба, обе.

  Родительный падеж (кого?, чего?): обоих, обеих.
```

***Дательный падеж*** (кому?, чему?): **обоим**, обеим.

**Винительный падеж** (кого?, что?): **обоих (одуш.)**, **оба (неодуш.);** обеих (одуш.), обе (неодуш.).

```
 Творительный падеж (кем?, чем?): обоими, обеими.

  Предложный падеж (о ком?, о чём?): об обоих, об 
 обеих.
```

**ВЫВОД**

1. Здесь **некорректное управление Д.п**.: написать двум театрам, обоим театрам. Написать можно ***кому-то***, но не **чему-то**. Нельзя писать письма  неодушевленному театру.
2. Поэтому надо использовать В.п. (куда?): написать **в  оба театра.** Или **обоим руководителям** театров.

**ОБОИ,** -ев; мн. Широкие полосы бумаги с рисунком (в прошлом - ткань, кожа) для оклейки (обивки) стен в помещениях.  Оклеить комнату обоями. Клей для обоев.

http://i.cdn01.ru/files/users/images/ba/0c/ba0c1cf4bd71923941490c21d1745f1a.jpg

Comment: Спасибо большое.